# Are there Cryptography certifications variants of CISSP?

Tags: random-number-generator

Are there Cryptography certifications variants of CISSP ( Certified Information Systems Security Professional)? Like a CISSP exams, but only for cryptography?

Answer (score 3):

The [EC Council](http://www.eccouncil.org/) offers some certification although I have no idea who they are. I think [CISSP](http://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/feature/CISSP-Essentials-training-Domain-3-Cryptography) implies you know about cryptography because you get examined on it although I don't know the depth they go into.

Other than that a Uni degree in security or cryptography would fit the bill, or a certificate from [Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/course/crypto) or related services, although that's of course not as prestigious as CISSP.

Comment: CISSP does not really cover the mathematical part of crypto.

Answer (score 0):

CISSP Study covers many Domains and in doing such a widespread coverage does not cover anything in any real depth. An example would be a functional knowledge and business use of Symmetric/Asymmetric Cryptography groups (As associated to the business capabilities the qualification seeks to support) I might suggest Universities seem to be the point to aim at for courses with any real meaning or SANS might have higher level referencing in its courses for the devoted..